# Should a trivial looking question with an URL be flagged as spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

Should questions flagged as spam, that's are very simple and have an URL in it?

For example
https://stackoverflow.com/q/34638260/3537677

consists only out of 1-2 sentences with the URL, where also no error can be found nor can it usually be used to debug the site.

It looks just like a trick to post spam, to me.

Comment: if it's spam, yeah. is it spam? doesn't look like spam. just looks like a poor quality question from someone who isn't a developer.

Comment: @KevinB That's the question. Looks like spam to me. If this is allowed, as a spamer I could ask thousands of questions like that, with just a automatic googled problem or bug keyword.

Comment: Yes, you could (well, definitely not thousands, but a few maybe), but you'd very quickly run into problems related to the throttling that occurs for low rep users who post low quality content.

Comment: In the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room we see a lot of spam posts. This isn't one of them.

Comment: @Superlokkus I you started seeing the same (or functionally the same) question thousands of times, then yes, it'd be pretty clear that the intent is to spam the site, and not to ask a question and just failing miserably at it.  Without evidence of lots of other questions like it, I'm far more likely to assume that it's just someone posting a terrible question, rather than spam.  Delete it for being a terrible question, which is what it is, not as spam, which it doesn't appear to be.

Comment: @KevinB Didn't know that. A little harsh that I got instantaneously downvoted ;-(

Comment: As Servy said, we get a lot of people who are working on websites and who think the best way to describe their problem is to point people to the site itself. They generally don't mean to promote their site, they just don't know how to assemble a self-contained description of their problem. I tend to dispute spam flags in these cases, unless they've done this in multiple posts with a clear intent to hide spam links.

Comment: Down votes on Meta often just mean disagreement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How simple the question is has no bearing on whether or not its spam.  If the post is actually advertising a product, rather than asking a question, flag it as spam.  If it's just a bad question, downvote/vote to close for whatever reason makes it a low quality question.